# Format an object into Date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column with dtype as Object and value is like 20210317. I am trying to convert this into dateformat mm/dd/yyyy. Below is the code i tried but it is throwing an error saying **KeyError 0**

```
df[EFFDT] = datetime.strptime(df['EFFDT'][0], '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try this: df['EFFDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EFFDT'],format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: if you want to access individual elements of a pd.Series (at a certain index), have a look at [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)